# How do I test the code in a "if (require.main === module)" section of a Node.js script using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have written a function like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  return 'text';
};
exports.myFunction = myFunction;
if (require.main === module) {
  console.log(myFunction());
}
```

and this is my test:

```
const { myFunction } = require('../myFunction');

describe('test', () => {
  it('should return the text', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toMatch('text');
  });
});
```

According to code coverage tools, every line in the code is covered **except for** this line line:

`console.log(myFunction());`

Based on comments, I think maybe the reality is that this line **cannot** be tested, so I'm updating my question:
How can I:

1. Test this line with Jest, understanding that it may **not** actually tick the "covered" box, but so I can literally test it. Because not every one of my files has such trivial code in that block. Sometimes I do want to test it for real.
2. Cause the coverage statistic to show the file as 100% covered? Not because I am pedantic, but I like using the coverage report to find things I need to add tests for, and having dozens of "false negatives" in my report makes that more difficult.

Comment: (devil's advocate) That line isn't exported.  How would it be available to be tested?

Comment: You should run it with a child_process call

Comment: If you want shiny 100% and don't want to rethink your approach add `/* istanbul ignore next */` :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That may actually be the best solution. Maybe I should reword my question to allow that as a possible answer?
I would **rather** actually be able to test code in that if block, but I honestly hadn't thought about just excluding it, and in some cases that may be the correct answer to "shiny 100%".

Comment: @Taplar Fair point. Are you suggesting that it is actually impossible to test code in that section of the code?

Comment: Or just stop worrying about 100% coverage... (note my screen name :))

Comment: It's inaccessable outside of that module.  That's the point of my first comment.  Also, all that logic is doing it performing a console.log.  One would question why that logic is needed in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a suggestion in the comments, I found that I can use a `child_process` `exec` call within the test to test the output from the command line like this:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const { myFunction } = require('../myFunction');

describe('test', () => {
  it('should return the text', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('text');
  });
  it('should return the text when called via command line too', async () => {
    const { stdout } = await exec('node myFunction', {
      encoding: 'utf8',
    });
    expect(stdout).toBe('text\n');
  });
});
```

Further comments pointed out that without exporting that section of code, Jest can never see it, and hence, never test it, meaning it will never show as "covered".  Therefore, once I am satisfied that it is "tested well enough" I can exclude it form my report by adding `/* istanbul ignore next */` before the offending line like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  return 'text';
};
exports.myFunction = myFunction;
if (require.main === module) {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  console.log(myFunction());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351150/3731501), Node.js `require` wraps script contents with wrapper code specified in `Module.wrapper` and evaluates it with `vm.runInThisContext`. This can be implemented in a test. It can be something like:

```
let Module = require('module');

...

jest.resetModules();
jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

let myModPath = require.resolve('../myFunction');
let wrapper = Module.wrap(fs.readFileSync(myModPath));
let compiledWrapper = vm.runInThisContext(wrapper, {});
let mockModule = new Module(myModPath);
let mockExport = mockModule.exports;
let mockRequire = Module.createRequire(myModPath);
mockRequire.main = mockModule;
    
wrapper(mockExport, mockRequire, mockModule, path.basename(myModPath), path.dirname(myModPath));

expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('test');
```