# Difference between NodeJs preload option (-r) and explicit require in in REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, preload, es6-modules

I'm using [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) which is a very useful package to support ES import keywords. According to the doc, in REPL, it can use preload command-line option to initialize it. i.e.
`node -r esm`

Or explicitly initialize in the REPL:

```
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./main.js")
```

Based on NodeJs help, `-r` is to preload a module with `require`. My question is why in REPL we can't just use:
`require("esm")` to achieve the same function as preload option `-r`; instead, we have to override the default `required` variable in the context to make it work.

Tried to figure out the magic by looking at `esm` source code. But it's a bit too difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Because code transformers like esm need to patch require in order to process nested modules, starting from the context where you do require=..., they cannot reach it themselves when imported like require("esm").

Comment: Thanks for the response. But how preloaded module with `-r` achieved the `require` patch. Not sure how esm do special handling in preloaded mode.

Comment: I'm quite sure it patches module wrapper https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper before any module is evaluated. It's responsible for how what happens when a module is loaded with require. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351150/3731501 for some explanation.